# Как организовать таблично совместимость знаков зодиака?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

В данный момент есть 2 табличка

1. Клиент:  ФИО, пол, возраст, место работы, рост,
   вес, знак Зодиака
2. Знак зодиака:  название, диапазон дат, **«совместимые» знаки**.

Как организовать эту самую "совместимость"?

Comment: Никак. Астрология - лженаука.

Comment: Этот сайт предназначен для ответа на технические вопросы. Вы  просите сформулировать вам в ответе набор бизнес-правил -- но это прерогатива заказчика ПО. Если же у вас в голове есть понимание, что именно вы хотите закодировать в ПО -- то нужно пояснить более подробно техническую задачу. Пока у меня представление, что вопрос смутно сформулирован и его нужно закрыть.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создайте таблицу знаков зодиака (если у Вас её ещё нет).
2. Создайте таблицу, в которой будут два поля, каждое из которых будет ссылаться на таблицу знаков зодиака. Добавьте туда "совместимые" пары.
3. Если в п.1 Вам пришлось создать таблицу, и в таблице клиентов лежит название знака - удалите это поле и замените его на поле, ссылающееся на таблицу знаков зодиака.
4. Используйте `JOIN` для получения знака зодиака клиента и "совместимых" знаков.